# What does "~~ *" mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

It used in this part of code:

```ruby
some_list.where("'#{@new_params[:email]}' ~~* name").any?
```

I tried to use google search, but i found only description of [~ rxp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-%7E) and this same unclear for me (especially in example). I had no experience with Ruby earlier, sorry if question is stupid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`~~*` doen't actually have anything to with Ruby. Its the [Postgres specific `ILIKE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-matching.html) for pattern matching.

This code is also a textbook example of a [SQL injection vulnerability](https://bobby-tables.com/). The user input should be parameterized.

```
some_list.where("? ~~* name", @new_params[:email]).any?
```

This code is also pretty bizarre in that it has a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). Normally you would write it as:

```
some_list.where("name ~~* ?", @new_params[:email]).any?
```

Comment: If you prefer named arguments over positional arguments you can use `some_list.where(":name ~~* name", name: @new_params[:email]).any?`

Comment: Now I understand, thanks! Yes, with named arguments and without Yoda style will be better, I think.

Comment: Wherever this code came from should be treated with a lot of suspicion. If its a project you took over you should install [brakeman](https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/introduction/) and do a security audit.

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing do do with ruby. You construct a sql query and pass it into the `#where` method therefor it is a PostgreSQL operator.

> The operator ~~ is equivalent to LIKE, and ~~* corresponds to ILIKE. There are also !~~ and !~~* operators that represent NOT LIKE and NOT ILIKE, respectively. All of these operators are PostgreSQL-specific.

That's what you are passing into it:

`"foo@bar.com ILIKE name"`

Answer (score 1):

Any string in a where clause will be put into the SQL query which is then handed off to the database. So the ~~* syntax is not ruby, but SQL. My guess would be, that you are using Postgres as a DB, because:

> The operator ~~ is equivalent to LIKE, and ~~* corresponds to ILIKE. There are also !~~ and !~~* operators that represent NOT LIKE and NOT ILIKE, respectively. All of these operators are PostgreSQL-specific.

Taken from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I understand, thanks!